Finding all five-digit squares that are divisible by $3$, have two $6$s and two $7$s as digits, and whose second digit from the right is odd
I was trying to solve the folowing number theory problem. I was asked to find all five-digit square numbers N that have the following propertys:

N is divisible by 3
in it's decimal represantation it has exactly two 6's and 7's (the fifth digit is unknown)
the second digit of N from the right is odd

From the first condition it follows that the fifth digit has to be 1, in order for this number to be divisible by 3. Then I noticed that N can not end with 7, since N is a square number. It also can not end with 1, because then the second digit from the right has to be 7 (by the third condition). But from that:$$N\equiv 71\equiv-1\pmod 4$$
which is impossible if N is a square number. From these arguments it is obvious that N must end with either 76 or 16. By using the second condition we end up with the following list of numbers:$$N\in\{71676, 76176, 61776,  67176, 16776, 17676, 77616, 76716, 67716\} $$ But this set is still to large to check by hand, and I'm asking You if there is any other way to reduce the number of "candidates" for N.

Why can't the fifth digit be $4$?

Since N is a square number, divisibility by 3 implies divisibility by 9. This means that the sum of the digits has to be divisible by 9. If we assume that the fifth number is x, then we get that 26+x must be divisible by 9. Also x is between 0 and 9, and thus the only number x can be is 1

Ah fair point! Very cool.

Here is another, simpler, way to discover which numbers among the nine candidates $16776,17676,61776,67176,67716,71676,76176,76716,77616$ is a perfect square. It still entails a bit of hand calculation.
We know that each number has been formulated to be divisible by $9$, and each number is even, so if it is a square, it must be divisible by $4$. Moreover, there may be more than one factor of either $4$ or $9$ in each candidate square. In order to be squares, the candidates must have the form $4^x9^yz^2$
We can serially remove factors of $4$ or $9$ from each candidate and ask if the quotient can be a square.
$16776 \rightarrow 4194 \equiv 2 \bmod 4$ not a square
$17676 \rightarrow 4419 \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ not a square
$61776 \rightarrow 15444 \rightarrow 3861 \rightarrow 429$
$67176 \rightarrow 16794 \equiv 2 \bmod 4$ not a square
$67716 \rightarrow 16929 \rightarrow 1881 \rightarrow 209$
$71676 \rightarrow 17919 \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ not a square
$76176 \rightarrow 19044 \rightarrow 4761 \rightarrow 529$
$76716 \rightarrow 19179 \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ not a square
$77616 \rightarrow 19404 \rightarrow 4851 \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ not a square
This eliminates six of the nine candidates, and reduces the problem to determining which if any of $209,429,529$ are squares. There are several easy ways of showing that among them only $529=23^2$ is a square. Only $76176$ among the candidates is a square.

The reasoning you present is spot on in terms of characterizing $N$. You can now proceed from the other direction, that is, thinking about what numbers can yield appropriate squares. It is not less handiwork, but it allows you to find the answer by taking squares, rather than abstracting square roots.
If $M=\sqrt{N}$ and $N$ ends in the digit $6$, then $M$ ends in one of the digits $4,6$
If $M=10a+4$ where $a$ is a single digit, then $M^2=100a^2+80a+16$. It the case that the last two digits of $M^2$ are $16,76$ when $a=0,2,5,7$. You can determine this by noticing that $4^2=16$ and adding $80$ to $16$ sequentially, determining how many multiples of $80$ added to $16$ give rise to last two digits $16,76$
Similarly, if $M=10a+6$ where $a$ is a single digit, then $M^2=100a^2+120a+36$. It is the case that the last two digits of $M^2$ are $16,76$ when $a=2,4,7,9$. You can determine this by noticing that $6^2=36$ and adding $20$ to $36$ sequentially, determining how many multiples of $20$ added to $16$ give rise to last two digits $16,76$. Adding $20$ is adequate, as the $100$ in $120$ has no effect on the last two digits of the sum.
We conclude that $M$ must end in the two digits $04,24,54,74$ or $26,46,76,96$
Finally, if $M=100b+c$ where $b$ is a digit and $c$ is one of the possible two digit endings for $M$, we can see that $b\ge 3$ will yield numbers that are too large ($300^2=90000>77616$). The numbers $104,124,126,146,154,174,176,196,204,224,226,246,254,274,276,296$ are candidates for $M$.
However, $3\mid N \Rightarrow 3\mid M$, so we can eliminate those candidates that are not divisible by $3$. This leaves $126,174,204,246,276$ Squaring these candidates reveals that only $276^2=76176$ is a solution that meets all of the criteria.

Wow, thanks a lot, i didn't even think about approaching it that way!
